# How to make sure the correct callback is processed?

Tags: 7, rules

I'm developing a module which add an action in Rules:

In the file .rules.inc I have:

```
function universal_document_creator_rules_action_info() {
  return array(
    'udc_createdoc' => array(
      'label' => t('Convert Docucument with UDC'),
      'group' => t('Custom'),
      'parameter' => array(
        'templateid' => array(
        'type' => 'integer',
        'label' => t('Template ID'),
        'description' => t('Enter the ID of the template'),
      ),
      'accountmanagersid' => array(
        'type' => 'integer',
        'label' => t('The number of the account manager'),
        'description' => t('The node ID of the number of the account manager.'),
      ),
      'filetypeid' => array(
        'type' => 'integer',
        'label' => t('File type ID'),
        'description' => t('The filetype ID. 1 = Word, 2 is PDF'),
      ),
      'cvnodeid' => array(
        'type' => 'integer',
        'label' => t('CV node ID'),
        'description' => t('The node ID from the CV'),
        ),
      ),
      'provides' => array(
        'filename' => array(
          'type' => 'text',
          'label' => t('File name'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

In file .module if have the function

```
<?php

// This callback creates the document using the parameters provided through rules' UI
function udc_createdoc($templateid, $accountmanagersid, $filetypeid, $cvnodeid) {

  $FileToSave == "foo";
  drupal_set_message(t('test why is this not on my screen'), 'error');

  return $FileToSave;

}
```

Setting the action in Rules UI is no problem but I do not get the message on the screen. Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems the format of return array is wrong in the `universal_document_creator_rules_action_info()`

Comment: Hi Jimmy, agree. As it is optional I deleted "provides". Still no result o of the drupal message on my screen :-(

Comment: I didn't try your code, but just read the rules.api.php. It seems `accountmanagersid`, `filetypeid`, `cvnodeid` are not valid keys.